# Use html forms for creating and updating json information

Tags: php, html, json

I have a simple html form that calls a php script to either create or update a file containing json script.

My html code,

```
<form name="inputs" method="post" action="parameters.php">
        Provide template name: <input type="text" name="templatename"><br>
        Which type? <select name="type"> <option value="abc">abc</option> <option value="def">def</option> <option value="ghi">ghi</option> </select><br>
        What name? <input type="text" name="name"><br>
        <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Here's parameters.php,

```
    <?php
            class Templates {
                    public $templatename = "";
                    public $type = "";
                    public $name = "";
            }

            $mytemplate = new Templates();
            $mytemplate->templatename = $_POST['templatename'];
            $mytemplate->type = $_POST['type'];
            $mytemplate->name = $_POST['name'];

            $data = json_encode($mytemplate);

            $templates = file_get_contents('users.txt');
            $templates = json_decode($templates);

            array_push($templates, $data);

            $fh = fopen("users.txt", "a");

            fwrite($fh, $templates);

            fclose($fh);
    ?>
```

This gives me the following output,

```
{"templatename":"1","type":"abc","name":"abc123"}{"templatename":"2","type":"def","name":"def123"}
```

The resulting json syntax is wrong. How can I add a new json element to preexisting json elements and how do I add a new json element when there're no previous json elements?

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the information that already exists in the file into memory, `json_decode()` it, than add the new object to an array of objects, `json_encode()` it, and overwrite the file.

Your data structure will likely be an array of objects for this case.

Currently, your code only tries to add a series of json-encoded objects to the file, making it to where you don't have valid JSON for the overall file.

I would say that if you expect your JSON representation to grow significantly, that this is a pretty inefficient way to handle this. You may want to consider a different type of persistence.

Comment: 1. I have updated my php code and this time I ended up with an empty users.txt. 2. Though I don't expect my JSON representation to grow significantly, can you please suggest alternatives?

Comment: @user2887201 My concern was just over case where you have thousadns or hundreds of thousand of items.  You would have to read them all into memory from file, deserialize, ad one new item, serialize, and write back to file. That is a lot of work to add one item.  If you had the items in a database for example, you could simply add an item at a time and just serialize to JSON as needed from the database.  You should show your updated code in your original question